# Laravel: Trying to get property of non-object although return value is right

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

**SOLVED**

I get this error when I got to a page where I call a method in template.

```
ErrorException in Product.php line 104:
Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\wamp64\www\ibpc\resources\views\admin\products\edit.blade.php)
```

In blade template I am calling a method attribute:

```
{{ $product->attribute($attribute->id) }}
```

$product in template is passed from controller as:

```
$product = Product::with('categories.specifications.attributes')->find($id);
```

Method attribute in Product.php:

```
public function attribute($id)
{
    $attribute = $this->attributes()->find($id);
    $test = $attribute->pivot->value;

    return $test;
}
```

I did debug with xdebug and everything seems to be fine:

[image]

Why the error?

If I do something like this then I get no errors:

```
public function attribute($id)
{
    return 'Hello';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to check for empty values...

```
public function attribute($id)
{
    $attribute = $this->attributes()->find($id);
    if ($attribute) {
        $test = $attribute->pivot->value;
    } else {
        $test = null;
    }

    return $test;
}
```